# How to use insomnia to make multiple requests and store results

Tags: insomnia

Is it possible to take a array of ids, make a separate call based on each ID, and the store the results in separate files using insomnia? I don't want to chain the calls. I have a preset list of IDs and I simply want to make those calls and then store the results in a text file automatically.

Comment: https://insomnia.rest/plugins/insomnia-plugin-batch-requests ?